# vsvim when input shift+each letter in insert mode, it add a '\n' automatically

Tags: vim, vsvim

I use vsvim and when I input 'shift+each letter' for a capital letter in the insert mode, it add a '\n' automatically. It puzzles me. Why does this happen and how can I avoid this?

Comment: This should not be happening.  What other extensions do you have installed?

Comment: Now I see why did this happen. There is a conflict between VsVim and 'Python intellisense Enhancer'. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments you have the Python Intellisense Enhancer extension installed.  This extension has a known bug that conflicts with VsVim (and really any other extension which uses the key mappings they have hard coded).

Essentially they are hard coding certain key combinations as starting intellisense.  Visual Studio itself though uses commands which are mapped to certain key combinations.  They are invoking intellisense by sending key strokes to the process instead of using a command or the intellisense API.  This causes VsVim, and other extensions, to see the key stroke instead of the command and hence they react as if the user had typed it

I filed a bug on them with a suggested work around some time ago but haven't gotten any response

- https://pyint.codeplex.com/workitem/1619